# C# - Save Variables of a Program

Tags: c#, variables, save

I'm making a game now in C# (which is a Console Application) and its variables need to be saved.

I've tried using Settings but there's a big problem about it: If the file name is changed or the file is transferred to somewhere else, the Settings are lost.

So what is a good alternative to Settings for saving variables and retrieving them later in the application?

EDIT: I'd like to save the variables to a text file and retrieve it later, is it possible? If yes, then how?

And please don't suggest online servers, because I'm working on a singleplayer game without keeping tracks of the players whatsoever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to store data of a fixed type is serialization with the BinaryFormatter class.

See the [MSDN documentation for Binary Formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I've copied some of the relevant code here.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

void SaveData() 
{
    // Create a hashtable of values that will eventually be serialized.
    Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
    addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
    addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
    addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

    // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,   
    // you must first open a stream for writing.  
    // In this case, use a file stream.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}


void LoadData() 
{
    // Declare the hashtable reference.
    Hashtable addresses  = null;

    // Open the file containing the data that you want to deserialize.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
    try 
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Deserialize the hashtable from the file and  
        // assign the reference to the local variable.
        addresses = (Hashtable) formatter.Deserialize(fs);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }

    // To prove that the table deserialized correctly,  
    // display the key/value pairs. 
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in addresses) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} lives at {1}.", de.Key, de.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your app structure is dynamic by it's nature, so it's name can be changed, location can be changed (even if , to be honest, don't understand reasons behind that) the only possibility I can see is relay in *external* source for retrieving or storing your config information.

In short: setup a server somewhere that holds your app configuration data, and on first startup try to reach that server, load file from it, read a data. If it fails, just load default information.

Good candidates could be : `DropBox`, `SkyDrive`, `GoogleDrive`, `Box`... find suitable C# API for any of them an store/read data you need. The only thing I would invite your attention to for this solution, is licensing. Keep an eye on it, and be sure that you *can* use it in your application in a way you decide to use it.

Comment: Online servers are not an option.

I meant that I want to save, by the easiest way, the information to an external .txt file and retrieve it later.

Comment: @BlueRay101 Then use settings.  They do just that.  The problem you claim to have is not mitigated in any way by manually creating/writing to a text file.

Comment: ok, but you are talking about a case when smeone just copied your app. So if you *can* guarantee that who copies will copy also related config files, you done, just save the data you need in another file. But, as much as I understood from your question, the problem is that you move only EXE from one PC to another.

Comment: Servy, the problem with Settings is that if the file path is changed, or the filename is changed, the Settings are LOST. Most chances are that users will frequently change the game's location or name, so I need a more reliable way to store information without that big risk of having it lost.

Comment: @Tigran No, what I meant is that the game will read from a file with a constant file name and file path, such as "save.txt". What I'm trying to do is that the user can easily change file's path and name without having to move any other files in order to preserve data.

Comment: @BlueRay101: Say you have game.exe and have game.config external. Which one you expect users gonna change/move ?

Comment: I expect game.config to stay at one place all the time, and no matter where game.exe is located, it'll always read information from game.config .

Comment: @BlueRay so my answer addresses exactly your issue. Put config in one place that everyone can access it from anywhere providing constant link to config: a server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40758/discussion-between-blueray101-and-tigran)

Comment: @BlueRay101 And I'm saying that that *exact same problem* exists if you use your own file.  I'm not saying that it doesn't exist for settings, it most certainly does, merely that your proposed "fix" doesn't actually fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the values out to a flat file...

Storing the values in an XML File, or a database file...

Windows Registry...

There are many places you can store information, and only experience will really teach you what to put where... To make an intelligent guess, you need to be familiar with all the approaches...

Comment: How would that be any different than a settings file.  It *is* a flat file, just like all of those.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Why?  The registry is a *terrible* place to store a large amount of information representing *data* about a program.  It should be for small amounts of information about configuration and such.

Comment: @Servy - true, I shouldn't expect the user to understand that term. Ok - how about "Straight text"?

Comment: @Servy - given the fact that the OP stated that he attempted to use a *Settings* file, IMHO it is safe to assume that he is only saving small amounts of data. If all he is looking for is a way to save some digits or a couple of strings for his apps configuration, then I think that registry is a creative solution, even if it's not necessarily the right one. Honestly, not being able to just store the settings in an XML file is a little silly, in my mind. When one installs a game, there is a reason why a directory is created for that game and its *data*.

Comment: @Servy Also, we don't know how much data the guy is wanting to save. Might just be last time they played, hi score etc... In other words, it might well only be small amounts of information. It wouldn't be my first choice either, but it is an option...

Comment: @Servy, I did upvote your and Tigran's answers though, as I do think they are better for most situations.

Answer (score 1):

The only real option that isn't susceptible to the user intentionally changing the data stored on their computer, losing it due to changing machines, etc. would be to not store the data on their computer at all.  Have a database or other server that you host that users connect to over the network which stores their data for them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)

> Isolated storage is not available for Windows Store apps. Instead, use
>   the application data classes in the Windows.Storage namespaces
>   included in the Windows Runtime API to store local data and files.

You may also try to use XML file to store the users setting and then store it in the **[SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)** directory.

You can also use the `app.config` file to save application-level settings

Comment: this is still computer related, so if you move your program, you will lost data.